# How to pass javascript variable to php to store in the database of wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I am building a star rating system in wordpress and so want to store rating data to wordpress database.
I am storing star rating php as a template in wordpress theme folder.Here is the part of the code.

```
<?php 
/* Template Name: RatingSystem */   
?>

<html>for displaying the stars</html>

<css>for hover and other star rating effects</css>

<script>
var r1;
var r2;
function submitForm() {
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'submit-rating.php',
         data: { r1 : r1 },
         success: function(data)
          {
            alert("success!");
           }
           });
                         }
function RatingValue(rating) 
{r1=rating;}    

function RatingValue1(rating1)
{r2=rating1;}   
</script>
```

submit-rating.php(PHP file).

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['r1']))
{
$rating = $_POST['r1'];
echo $rating;
}
?>
```

But when i do echo $rating no output is displayed.Why?Also please explain how to store in wordpress database.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your output isn't displayed because JS doesn't "know" it should display it.
Instead of

```js
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'submit-rating.php',
         data: { r1 : r1 },
         success: function(data)
         {
            alert("success!");
         }
    });                        
}
```

try

```js
function submitForm() {
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'submit-rating.php',
         data: { r1 : r1 },
         success: function(data)
         {
            alert(data);
         }
    });                        
}
```

The `data` in `function(data)` is the response the JS gets. In order to show it in a div, you could use `$('#divID').html(data)` where the `alert` is.

-- Edit: forgot the second part of your question.

I recommend you use `WPDB` for posting your data in your wordpress database. This is possible if this PHP file is part of the template, or if you have turned off the template engine for that file and required the wp_load.php. If neither of these apply, I recommend you do the latter by including this at the top of your php file

```
// Include WordPress
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('PATH/TO/wp-load.php');
```

Information on `WPDB` and how to use it can be found [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#INSERT_row).

Comment: Thanks for your time in answering my question.I replaced alert("success!") with alert(data),but it still shows no alert when the function is invoked.Why?Also i want insert database queries to be inside submit-rating.php(which is another php file located in the same theme folder).

Comment: Also can you give some good sources for knowing all this(especially about ajax for using to pass javascript variables to another php file.)?

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console (CTRL+SHIFT+I in chrome)? I think the problem might be the url, try ``/path/to/theme/submit-rating.php``. 

As for sources, I believe [link](https://webdesignerhut.com/pass-data-with-ajax-to-a-php-file/) sums it up quite nicely.

Comment: I am buiilding this in wordpress.org,so i am putting 'localhost/mysite/wp-content/themes/zincy-lite/submit-rating.php' as the url.Is that correct way to put it,because i am still not getting any alert?

Comment: Is there any way you can send me the link, so I can see it?

Comment: I think i found another way to do this in the same file.I am using a variable in javascript function and this variable will be set a value if javascript function is called.The php will have if for checking whether the variable is set or not and value is passed onto the database from that php.